# Reading from multiple COM ports individually in pyqt LineEdit widget

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, barcode-scanner, qlineedit

I am developing a device and I am using pyqt to develop a GUI for reading from multiple USB barcode scanners via a **qlineedit** widget. Barcode scanners act like keyboards, except that each one has a specific COM port and moreover it returns an **ENTER** character at the end of the barcode string.
But there is a serious problem when barcode is detectable by more than one barcode scanner (which cannot be prevented because the configuration of these scanners is imposed by device mechanical design). In such a situation, data from these COM ports are sent simultaneously and hence the received string is a randomly merged form of characters of the barcode. Is there anyway to handle this problem? For example by using multiple **qlineedit** widgets, each connected to one of the COM ports.

Thanks

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QLabel
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineedit.returnPressed.connect(self.onPressed)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        hbox.addWidget(self.label)
        hbox.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.show()


    def onPressed(self):
        self.label.setText(self.lineedit.text())
        self.lineedit.setText('')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: Probably, it is a difficult problem with the articles on these Q&A site. Asking for consulting by a technical expert will save you time.

Comment: Then the relevance and configuration between acting like a keyboard and each having a specific COM port seems underexplained. What do they mean and what are the requirements? Normally, the scanner's keyboard input emulation and COM port configuration are exclusive settings, and you should only be able to use one or the other. Even if you ask an expert or consultant, it's a good idea to organize such information so that you can explain it accurately.